# Accessing Dashboard usage data in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho

I have an idea about creating a dashboard that shows the usage statistics of my Pentaho dashboards. It would generally show which dashboards are being used how much and by whom.
I know this information is in some logs somewhere but I would appreciate pointers on where to look and if anyone has implemented anything of the sort, I'd love some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are audit tables in the Hibernate database.

Look for table PRO_AUDIT, it includes things like username, action requested, timestamp, etc. It still requires a lot of parsing, but it’s easier than going through the log files.

Comment: Awesome! The table has everything I need.